# appcode cannot find Drop Frame button

Tags: appcode

Why my AppCode cannot find "Drop Frame" button and "Dump" button when debugging?

Drop Frame : Interrupts execution and returns to the initial point of method execution. In the process, it drops the current method frames from the stack.

Dump: Dump the threads statement

This is Appcode help page：https://www.jetbrains.com/help/objc/2017.1/debug-tool-window.html?utm_medium=help_link&utm_source=from_product&utm_campaign=OC&utm_content=2017.1#debugtoolbar

[Sorry I am poor in English,my question may be difficult to understand]
[enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAH31.png)

Comment: Please take some time to rewrite your question in some proper text. Describe what those buttons are and what exactly you did and what you expected. Try to use proper english.

Comment: Thanks, I am so sorry for my bad English , I  have reedit my question

Comment: Sorry for the misleading help article, unfortunately these actions are not implemented in AppCode/CLion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ， it is useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Drop Frame" functionality is not implemented in AppCode. It's presence in the Help is a mistake and should be fixed.

Comment: Hi Vyacheslav Karpukhin Thank you for your scrupulous answer ,"Dump" button could not find in Appcode，it is also a mistake? && How can I  step back my debug position like visual studio ?

Comment: It's not possible at the moment.